# Wordpress: excerpt only for Woocommerce Brand pages

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

Dear StackOverflow friends,
in a Wordpress E-store, we use Woocommerce and its extension plugin Woocommerce Brand Addon.

I'd like this code (located in functions.php) to be applied **only to Woocommerce Brand pages**: the code does its job in Woocommerce Brands but it is applied also in other categories/archives

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item_title', 'lk2_woocommerce_product_excerpt', 35, 2);
if (!function_exists('lk2_woocommerce_product_excerpt'))
{
function lk2_woocommerce_product_excerpt()
{
$content_length = 20;
global $post;
$content = $post->post_excerpt;
$wordarray = explode(' ', $content, $content_length + 1);
if(count($wordarray) > $content_length) :
array_pop($wordarray);
array_push($wordarray, '...');
$content = implode(' ', $wordarray);
$content = force_balance_tags($content);
endif;
echo "<span class='excerpt'><p>$content</p></span>";
}
}
```

I played with 'taxonomy' and 'include', inserting ID of Brands, but no results. Here is my last attempt.

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item_title', 'lk2_woocommerce_product_excerpt', 35, 2);
if (!function_exists('lk2_woocommerce_product_excerpt'))
{
function lk2_woocommerce_product_excerpt()
{
$content_length = 20;
global $post;
$args = array(
'include'            => '120,121,122,123,124,125,126,127',
'taxonomy'           => 'product_brand',
); 
$content = $post->post_excerpt;
$wordarray = explode(' ', $content, $content_length + 1);
if(count($wordarray) > $content_length) :
array_pop($wordarray);
array_push($wordarray, '...');
$content = implode(' ', $wordarray);
$content = force_balance_tags($content);
endif;
echo "<span class='excerpt'><p>$content</p></span>";
}
}
```

Unfortunately we haven't bought a domain yet, so I can't show you a link.

I could fix the output with css, but I'd prefer to solve directly from the code.
Can you help me in finding the direction to fix my error? Thanks for your time!

Comment: Is "brand" a type of taxonomy? Couldn't you use conditional logic inside the function?

Comment: @helgatheviking sorry for asking, but what is `taxonomy`?

Comment: [Taxonomies](http://codex.wordpress.org/Taxonomies) are a way to group things together. Tags and Categories are built-in taxonomies for Posts. Product Tags and Product Categories are taxonomies for Products that are created by WooCommerce.

Comment: Yes, product_brand is a type of taxonomy, registered by Woocommerce Brand Plugin! Ok thanks @helgatheviking I tried and played with conditional logic!

Comment: I had to ask because I am not familiar with that particular plugin. The more information you can give in questions the easier it is for people to help you... especially when dealing with premium plugins that not everyone has access to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for all your directions! Here is the code, thanks to David

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item_title', 'lk_woocommerce_product_excerpt', 35, 2);
if (!function_exists('lk_woocommerce_product_excerpt')){
    function lk_woocommerce_product_excerpt(){
        $content_length = 10;
        if(get_query_var('product_brand'))
            $content_length = 20;
        global $post;
        $content = $post->post_excerpt;
        $wordarray = explode(' ', $content, $content_length + 1);
        if(count($wordarray) > $content_length) :
        array_pop($wordarray);
        array_push($wordarray, '...');
        $content = implode(' ', $wordarray);
        $content = force_balance_tags($content);
        endif;
        echo "<span class='excerpt'><p>$content</p></span>";
    }
}
```

Comment: if(get_query_var('product_brand')) is what I was looking for

Comment: `if(is_taxonomy('product_brand'))` should also work. Glad you got it sorted in the end.

Answer (score 0):

This looks like it might have the answer: [If is custom post type](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/6731/if-is-custom-post-type)

```
if (is_single() && is_post_type('product_brand')){
  //work magic
}
```

Comment: You can combine this to be `is_singular('product_brand')`.

Comment: Thank you keepkalm and @helgatheviking, it's interesting: I'll keep your precious tips in mind for the future (but I wasn't able to use them successfully with my code)